# Why is npm giving 500 and 503 errors: "registry error parsing json"?

Tags: node.js, npm, steroids

Trying to do `npm install steroids -g` and running into lots of errors of two types:

**First: 500**

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 500 https://registry.npmjs.org/cardinal
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 500 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 500 https://registry.npmjs.org/chmodr
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 500 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
```

when I visit those urls in the browser I get the following message:

> Internal routing error
>
> Sorry, we cannot connect to the intended server.
>
> We have just been notified of this problem. We will correct it as soon
>   as possible.
>
> Feel free to contact us if you have any questions:
>   support@iriscouch.com

**Second: 503**

```
npm http 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/diff
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
```

When I visit those urls in the browser I get this message:

> Error 503 backend read error
>
> backend read error
>
> Guru Meditation:
>
> XID: 1448084160
>
> Varnish cache server

Does this mean the npm registry is down? or do I have strange behavior on my machine?

Running node v.0.10.24 & npm v.1.3.21

Comment: npm does go down from time to time.  The load it is under is extraordinary.  It's worth checking its Twitter feed at https://twitter.com/npmjs.

Comment: I still find it redonculous that npm isn't handling the 5** codes and tries to parse the response as JSON instead.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try using a mirror for example the european mirror:

```
npm --registry http://registry.npmjs.eu/ install karma
```

Comment: +1 @joketres!
Good to know! RaphaelDLL's answer is true - should check twitter before asking on SO - but your hint is useful for "what to do if it is indeed down?"

Comment: Looks like it's down again; this fixed it for me.  npm puts the full HTTP error message into npm-debug.log.

Comment: To make this permanent, run `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.eu` Beware that you cannot publish packages to a mirror. http://shapeshed.com/using-the-european-npm-mirror/

Comment: Thank you, @sigurdga! I tried publishing to a mirror and got error 405 - "Not Allowed". I have not been able to publish all day. Very annoying, when working on dependencies of other projects.

Answer (score 16):

From [@npmjs](https://twitter.com/npmjs/status/423185634581176320) around 15mins after your question was made:

> "aware of the outage. please be patient. working to resolve this now."

On side note, read [Node Roundup: Surviving npm Downtime, Waf Wall of Shame, stream-chat, Vein](http://dailyjs.com/2012/08/15/node-roundup/), interest info about NPM mirrors. Kinda outdated (2012) but now you know it has mirrors ;-)

Also, a good advice by 'mark' at the comments of this blogpost I linked:

> If you're relying on NPM for production deployments, STOP! Make sure you set specific versions and clone them in your private repo. Deploy from your private repo not the NPM registry. You have been warned. Relying on NPM for production deployment scripts has bitten us twice! The first was because a library author deleted an old version of his library we depended on. This time it was the NPM registry itself.

Comment: It's very confusing when it's not clear why something isn't working and it turns out to be a one off thing like the registry server being down!

Answer (score 1):

npm has a status page where any server incidence will (should) be reflected:

https://status.npmjs.org