# npm not installing tar package from cache when forced

Tags: node.js, caching, npm

I'm using Node v5.0.0 and npm v3.3.6 and running into a very isolated issue with he [tar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar) package. Due to corporate firewalls I was forced to clone the Git repository and install it from that

My problem is that despite forcing npm to install packages from the cache, `tar` is the *only* package that insists on downloading it from npm's registry.

```
$ npm install tar@2.2.1 --verbose --cache-min=999999999999                                     
npm info it worked if it ends with ok                                                                                                        
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',                                                                                        
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',                                                              
npm verb cli   'install',                                                                                                                    
npm verb cli   'tar@2.2.1',                                                                                                                  
npm verb cli   '--verbose',                                                                                                                  
npm verb cli   '--cache-min=999999999999' ]                                                                                                  
npm info using npm@3.3.6                                                                                                                     
npm info using node@v5.0.0                                                                                                                   
npm verb get http://registry.npmjs.org/tar not expired, no request                                                                           
npm verb cache add spec tar@2.2.1                                                                                                            
npm verb addNamed "2.2.1" is a plain semver version for tar                                                                                  
npm verb addNameVersion registry:http://registry.npmjs.org/tar not in flight; fetching                                                       
npm verb get http://registry.npmjs.org/tar not expired, no request                                                                           
npm verb addRemoteTarball http://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz not in flight; adding                                                
npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz',                                                                 
npm verb addRemoteTarball   '8e4d2a256c0e2185c6b18ad694aec968b83cb1d1' ]                                                                     
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 8:38:23 AM                                                                                                 
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 8:38:23 AM                                                                                       
npm http fetch GET http://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz                                                                             
npm verb request id b8672d43f7b2c569                                                                                                         
npm http fetch 503 http://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz                                                                             
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: server error 503
```

I've double checked my cache and can see that tar v2.2.1 is in fact present and functional.

```
$ npm cache list | grep 'tar\\2.2.1'
~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\tar\2.2.1
~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\tar\2.2.1\package
~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\tar\2.2.1\package.tgz
~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\tar\2.2.1\package\package.json
```

For what it's worth, I'm able to overcome this issue by simply adding the project's Git repository in my dependencies folder and use `npm install deps/node-tar` before doing `npm install`. Still doesn't explain the problem at hand, however.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but for me it works as expected, installing from the cache. I notice in your output, however, the line **npm http fetch 503 http://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz** which suggest some issue actually downloading the tarball. I recommend trying again, and looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122814/why-is-npm-giving-500-and-503-errors-registry-error-parsing-json) which addresses the 503 issue.

Also, could you post the result of `npm cache ls tar`

Comment: Guess what I'm not understanding is why `npm` is trying to download the file at all since I'm forcing the cache using `--cache-min` and the logs show `npm verb get http://registry.npmjs.org/tar not expired, no request`. To me that means that `npm` will not be issuing a request to download the `tar` package.